# setter with sort return in Java

Tags: java, set

In the setters and getters on the set I would like the method that returns this alphabetically ordered. How can I do it?

This is my code:

```
public Long getIdPaisNacionalidad() {
    return  paisNacionalidad != null ? paisNacionalidad.getId() : null;
}
```

And I would like something similar to:

```
public Long getIdPaisNacionalidad() {
    return  paisNacionalidad != null ? paisNacionalidad.getId().sort() : null;
}
```

Comment: I don't see why this single Long needs to be sorted, let alone alphabetically; maybe give some more context

Comment: As @UmshiniWami said, show us more details about why you are doing this please.

Comment: I have an array of countries which I have to organize alphabetically. But in the code that gave me the definition of the method that gives me back the countries is the first option that I showed them. I just want to know if it can be organized as the second option that I show you, or if there is another way. @UmshiniWami

Comment: @terry.qiao I have an array of countries which I have to organize alphabetically. But in the code that gave me the definition of the method that gives me back the countries is the first option that I showed them. I just want to know if it can be organized as the second option that I show you, or if there is another way

Comment: @FelixAVeras I still don't get your point. Would you want to share a small testable code?